# Android 11 and File API support

Tags: java, android, storage-access-framework, scoped-storage

The following article mentions that Android 11 allows for usage of the `File` API (under the title `Access files using direct file paths and native libraries`).

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

I would like more information on this. Does this refer to `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission or does it speak in general. If it does not mean `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission then what does it mean exactly?

1. If I use Storage Access Framework to persist a path. After persistence, can I use the `File` class to create and save a file in that persistent path using the `File` class? For example:

```
 File file = new File(filePath);
 FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
 OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
 out.write(downloadedSubtitles);
 out.close();
```

2. Can I use the `File` class to read a file within the persisted path?
3. Can I use `file://` paths?

I also have different related question. Can I use the `File` class with the code above to write files into the app's folder?

Thank you.

Comment: `After persistence, can I use the File class to create and save a file in that persistent path using the File class?` No you cant. And your example code does not work which you could have told us right away. Why didnt you?

Comment: For 2: no you cant.

Comment: For 3: use that to do what?

Comment: `Can I use the File class with the code above to write files into the app's folder?` Yes. But we do not know what you consider to be the apps folder.